# passing the value in angular from a modal

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a modal window in Angular which opens when a button is pressed.

When the modal is open I have a list of buttons with images inside them. The example of this is below.

I am trying to detect when `ng-click="chosen(pink)"` happens so that it writes to the main apps `$scope`with the value `pink` but when I run the below it writes to the console.log `undefined`

**angular**

```
    $scope.choosepin = function () {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'template/modal-choose-pin.html',
            controller: ModalInstanceCtrl3,
            resolve: {},
            scope: $scope.$new()
        });
        modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
            $scope.user.pin = selectedItem;
            console.log($scope);
        });

    };

ModalInstanceCtrl3 = function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
        $scope.input = [];

        $scope.ok = function () {
            $modalInstance.close($scope.pin);
            $scope.gps = "";
            $scope.title = "";
        };

        $scope.cancel = function () {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };

        $scope.chosen = function(index) {
            console.log(index);
        }
    };
```

**html**

```
<button type="button" ng-click="chosen(pink)"><img src="/mapbuilder/assets/img/markers/pin-pink.png" /></button>
```

Comment: I think pink has to be enclosed in single quotes otherwise angular thinks it is a variable.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-click` directive expecting [expression](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) and because of that it looks for a $scope variable with name *pink*, and of course it is undefined because you do not have such variable in your controller.

if you want to send **String** as a parameter you should do it like this,

```
ng-click="chosen('pink')"
```